# Partially deserialize the spring session object stored in hazelcast

Tags: spring-mvc, hazelcast, spring-session, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using hazelcast for session replication in spring application which is an mvc app. I have a separate app which is an api gateway(spring cloud gateway) which has hazelcast client to be able to read hazelcast session details from mvc app.

Spring session stores session details in hazelcast in following format:

```
session Id => MapSession
                          -> id = "xyz"
                          -> sessionAttrs 
                                          -> session attributes set if any
                                          -> SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT = SecurityContextImpl
```

My hazelcast client when tries to read the session map using session id

```
hazelcastInstance.getMap("spring:session:sessions").get(sessionId)
```

fails with error **HazelcastSerializationException**, cause **SecurityContextImpl.class not found**. This class will not be present in spring cloud gateway app as it is reactive one. I don't care about about SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT attribute at gateway side. I just need other session attributes that I set. So is it possible to ignore SecurityContextImpl and still deserialize MapSession? please help.

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast supports defining a custom serializer for any class, including `java.io.Serializable` classes. 
You can register a custom serializer for `MapSession` class and skip reading `SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT` attribute.

```
static class MapSessionSerializer implements StreamSerializer<MapSession> {

    @Override
    public void write(ObjectDataOutput out, MapSession object) throws IOException {
        // write attributes
    }

    @Override
    public MapSession read(ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {
        MapSession mapSession = new MapSession();
        // read attributes
        return mapSession;
    }

    @Override
    public int getTypeId() {
        return typeId;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}

[...]

SerializerConfig serializerConfig = new SerializerConfig()
    .setTypeClass(MapSession.class)
    .setImplementation(new MapSessionSerializer());

config.getSerializationConfig().addSerializerConfig(serializerConfig);
```

See [Hazelcast custom serialization](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#custom-serialization) section for more info.